# How can I run two cycles in one repo on travis?

Tags: travis-ci

I've got two directories on the root of my repo: `client` and `server`; how can I run two different cycles (with pre_install, install, script &c), one on each of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse into the desired directories and run all subsequent commands in them:

```
before_install:
  - pushd client
  - ./pre-install-client
  - popd
  - pushd server
  - ./pre-install-server
  - popd
```

These you can reproduce in all relevant sections and run commands in both the client and server directories. I'd recommend extracting these things to shell scripts if possible to reduce the complexity of the `.travis.yml` file.